# Why Windows 10 Blocks some LAN IPs (192.168..)?

Tags: windows-10, windows-firewall, hosts-file, chrome, windows-defender

**- Summarize the problem:**

Windows 10 does not allow visiting my local LAN IPs (192.168.1.0/24), and some domains (that are defined in my hosts file). Error shows in all browsers (e.g. form chrome: *Firewall or antivirus software may have blocked the connection.*)

**- what you’ve tried:**

1. I tried to check if `chrome` is allowed by windows firewall and it
   is.
2. I tried to disable `Windows Firewall` in my private network and it did
   not fix it.
3. I tried using another machine on the same router and it works fine,
   i can access (192.168.1.1 - router).
4. I cleared my `DNS cache` (to test the modified hosts domains properly)
       and the browser won't load them. Although `PING` works as
       defined in the hosts file.

Comment: you may have to use iexplore. exe to test access as Chrome seems to me to ignore the hostfils

Comment: i tried internet explorer, chrome, and firefox nothing works..

Comment: What precisely are you entering into the URL bar?

Comment: http:// 192.168.1.1 (without the space)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue. it was my VPN app making my laptop from my lan as (invisible feature)

Answer (score 0):

hi it seems some thing block your subnet.if you didnot do any special config on your win10 please test these :

1. Disable all 3 firewall(for a short time to tshoot)
2. Flush your DNS(ipconfig /flushdns) if you can not connect them with domain name and arp cache (arp -d *(open cmd with elevetion ))
3. Check if your system IP address is in correct range .
4. Self ping the system (to check if tcp/ip is working right)
5. Check cable and switch connection
6. Ping another system in your subnet
7. Disable/Enable NIC
8. Run this in cmd netsh int ip reset